# how to view weighted frequency directly in round figure

Tags: stata

I have a list of variables in Stata. i am weighting the DHS dataset and found:

```
tab sp_age [iw=wt]


(husband/
partner's 
age)       Freq.    Percent Cum.
        
15-29  1,631.5409   32.08   32.08
30-44  2,426.9487   47.72   79.81
45-59  941.139558   18.51   98.31
60+   85.744955 1.69    100.00
        
Total  5,085.3741   100.00
```

I want to display frequencies as integers and percentages to  1 decimal place,  but I am not able to solve this in Stata.

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue, you can try rounding the weight itself:

```
ta sp_age [iw = round(wt, 1)]
```

If that doesn't work, you'll have to use some sort of workaround. I suggest following [this thread.](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1508840-how-to-display-frequencies-and-percentages-to-whole-numbers-only-in-stata-se-15-1)

Comment: this command works but it destroys the actual weight value. so not recommended

Comment: Rounding weights is very common in survey research, I'm not sure I understand what you mean when you use the word "destroy."

Comment: i means the table does not come appropriately. example: using just iweight the total number come 4090.13 which i can write like round figure 4090 but doing round through ta sp_age [iw = round(wt, 1)]  commnd the total comes 3890. which totally different